# How to stop animation repeating itself in staggered animation (chain animation) when it is completed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying create wave animation like instagram when you record voice in the chat, when the wave is getting added and also it's height being animated.

So when ever new data is added I'm adding an Object to list which contains wave height and a `Animation<double>`.

which look like this,

```
class Wave {
  double db;
  Animation<double> animation;

  Wave(this.db, this.animation);
}
```

```
late AnimationController _controller;

  final List<Wave> _waves = [];
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
widget.waveController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      _controller.forward();
      if (widget.waveController.recorderState == RecorderState.recording &&
          widget.waveController.waveData.isNotEmpty) {
        _waves.add(Wave(
            widget.waveController.waveData.last,//<-----height
            Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
         parent: _controller, curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5)))));//<----animation object
      }
    });
 _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _controller.reset();
      }
    });
}
```

now in custom painter,

```
class WavePainter extends CustomPainter {


...


@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

   canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(
            -totalBackDistance.dx +
                dragOffset.dx +
                (spacing * i) -
                initialPosition,
            size.height - bottomPadding),
        Offset(
            -totalBackDistance.dx +
                dragOffset.dx +
                (spacing * i) -
                initialPosition,
            -waves[i].db * waves[i].animation.value //<----animating the height
       + size.height - bottomPadding),
        _wavePaint);

}

}
```

But what happens here is that it keeps repeating the animation for all previous waves.

So how can I stop repetition if a waves animation is completed?
do I have to give separate `animationController` to each object? wouldn't it consume more memory over time?

Or this the correct way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `_controller.forward();` called inside another controller's listener (i mean called on every listener tick)? what kind of animation should the custom painter draw?

Comment: and if the animation has to be repeated again and again why dont you use `AnimationController.repeat()` method?

Comment: @pskink I want to achieve audio waveform with this and it working but I want that smooth instagram like animation

Comment: @pskink and I want if one wave's animation is completed then it should not repeat. You can check it in instagram app and record voice in chat, how height is being animated of newer wave

Comment: i dont have any instagram app so i cannot tell